# function to get the name of any method?

Tags: c#

I would like to have a function called **GetMethodName** such that the following code would print "myMethod":

```
int myMethod(string foo, double bar)
{
    // ...
}

Console.Out.WriteLine(GetMethodName(myMethod));
```

This should work no matter what the method signature myMethod has.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
public static string GetMethodName(Expression<Action> exp)
{
    var b = (MethodCallExpression)exp.Body;
    return b.Method.Name;
}

// ...


var name = GetMethodName(() => myMethod(string.Empty, 0.0));
System.Out.WriteLine(name);
```

Answer (score 11):

No, it's not possible like that. It would be possible with the [mythical `infoof` operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx) which the C# team would *like* to include, but haven't got round to yet - but without that, you'd have to use a method group conversion, which will only work if you know the specific type of delegate to use.

The closest you can probably come is to use an expression tree:

```
public static string GetMethodName(Expression expression)
{
    // Code to take apart the expression tree and find the method invocation
}

GetMethodName(() => myMethod(0, 0));
```

That wouldn't actually need to *call* `myMethod`, but you would need to provide dummy arguments - which could be irritating if there are any out/ref parameters.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out on [Eric Lippert's](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx) blog you could fake it with the Action and Func delegates

```
public static MethodInfo GetInfo<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    return action.Method;
}
public static MethodInfo GetInfo<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func)
{
    return func.Method;
}
public static MethodInfo GetInfo<T, U, TResult>(Func<T, U, TResult> func)
{
    return func.Method;
}   
public static int Target(int v1, int v2)
{
    return v1 ^ v2;
} 
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var mi = GetInfo<string[], int>(Main);
    Console.WriteLine(mi.Name);

    var mi2 = GetInfo<int, int, int>(Target);
    Console.WriteLine(mi2.Name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd need umpteen variants for different parameters though - including combinations of ref/out as well :(

Comment: true... but it is possible.  I had a sample that was up to 4 inputs (count on Func and Action) but I figured that was too much code for a quick sample.

Comment: how would GetInfo distinguish between a void method taking 2 int arguments on the one hand and an int method taking 1 int argument on the other?

Comment: you have to overload the method as Jon said

Answer (score -1):

Something like the below?

new StackFrame(1, false).GetMethod().Name

:Edit to add code sample...

```
    public string PrintMethodName()
    {
        return new StackFrame(1, false).GetMethod().Name;
    }

    private void Hi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(PrintMethodName());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Misunderstood the question. It actually helps reading the question.

<strike>You can use Reflection:</strike>

[MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod(VS.80).aspx) returns the current running method.

Comment: There's nothing to indicate that it's the current method. It's just a random method he wants to get the name of.

Comment: It was my first guess too - then I took the unusual step of reading the question ;) (I've done this *so* many times myself...)

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is doable. Look at class StackFrame and its GetMethod.

EDIT: looks like I misunderstood the original question. Never mind my original answer.

Comment: See my response to Mircea. There's nothing in the question to suggest the OP wants to get the *current* method.